# AJAX load HTML code to div from post response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, request

I want to load simple html code to my parent div, after post request with AJAX.

HTML:

```
<div id="html-container"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#html-container").empty();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "src/items.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {stype:st},
        success : function(data) { 
        $('#html-container').html(data);
    },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

    });
```

Also tryed *$('#html-container').text(data)*, *$('#html-container').load(data)*

PHP:

```
if (array_key_exists('stype', $_POST)) {

        $dataStr = funcs_to_generate_html_code();
        echo "$dataStr";

  } else {

        $dataStr = func_to_generate_html_code();
        echo "$dataStr";

    }
```

Problem is:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

But in dev tools (Network -> XHR -> Response) no errors, just html code what I need.

In PHP: *echo json_encode($dataStr);* returns ruined html code, and without **json_encode** just with **echo** I still get error (above).

How can I get and set HTML code to div from response of post request with AJAX?

**UPD**:

Setting *dataType: "text"*, and *dataType: "html"* removes error above, and I can see all html code in browser inspector, but can't see it actually in my div, if I set *$('#html-container').text(data)* all html loads to div as simple text.

Comment: did you try changing the dataType to "text" just to see what is being gotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your return `datatype` as per the documentation:

> **dataType** - (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
>   Type: String The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4
>   JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the
>   script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

So the Jquery code will looks like this:

```
$("#html-container").empty();

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "src/items.php",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {stype:st},
        success : function(data) { 
            $('#html-container').html(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Or even you can remove `dataType` from the `ajax`
 method to receive any data:

```
$("#html-container").empty();

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "src/items.php",
            data: {stype:st},
            success : function(data) { 
                $('#html-container').html(data);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your backend code like below.

```
if (array_key_exists('stype', $_POST)) {
    $dataStr = funcs_to_generate_html_code();
    echo json_encode(array( 'html' => $dataStr ));
} else {
    $dataStr = func_to_generate_html_code();
    echo json_encode(array( 'html' => $dataStr ));
}
```

Javascript code to append html to dom.

```
$("#html-container").empty();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "src/items.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { stype: st },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#html-container').html(data.html);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

> I will recommend to send just "data" from backend and then use javascript to create new HTML elements and modify the dom with those new elements.